# At what time can you start feeding Mogwai?

Tags: gremlins

You can't feed Mogwai after midnight because otherwise they turn into [Gremlins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gremlins).

But what time is safe again?

Comment: I think you need to wait for a long period of time. Just to be fully safe, 23 hours and 59 minutes is a good idea.

Comment: Mogwai operates on strict [Greenwich Mean Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time), that's what confuses most owners.

Comment: A downvote? Why?

Comment: I upvoted you. While I liked the movie as a kid, I don't think _Gremlins_ makes any sense. It doesn't follow any sort of logic. I think [Joe Dante](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Dante) was just screwing with us :)

Comment: I don't have anything to back this up, but my feeling would say dawn in when it becomes safe again.

Comment: I have spawned fun.  Wooo!

Comment: +1 for you! We often debate on the topic...and I think the time is dawn. In the winter the Mogwai are hungry longer than in the summer ;)

Comment: @Wikis - I didn't DW but considered to, precisely for the reason Andres up-voted. There's no info to properly answer it.

Comment: @DVK: then that's the answer! That "there is no answer" was not known at the time of asking the question, otherwise the question would not be asked.

Comment: @MarkRogers I think it its actually Gremlin Mean Time (GMT)

Comment: @Mentoliptus: Mogwaii can't live above or below a certain point, or they'd starve after midnight (29 days until dawn!)

Comment: I would say rather Gremlin Meal Time

Comment: logically, it's always midnight somewhere so they should never eat :)

Comment: Technically the furthest from midnight would be noon. So assuming they can ever eat, noon would be the safest distance from midnight.

Comment: I always wondered that.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There's no real explanation given, and in fact these questions are raised in the film series itself.

There's also no rational explanation given for the transition of a mammal into a reptile.  It just happens.

The only possible explanation is magic.

Following the common themes of magic, I would assume it's a problem between the witching hour (midnight) and dawn - dawn being the typical start of a new day, with new beginnings, and generally presumed to have mystical significance.

Comment: +1 for magic. Much better explanation than "_Gremlins_ doesn't make sense!"

Comment: @Plutor - Gremlins DOES make sense... once you add magic!

Comment: Who said they were reptiles? Some mammals have scaly skin (armadillos?), and some of the gremlins still had hair (albeit in mohawk form...).

Comment: @KevinWorkman: They're repeatedly described as 'reptilian' in the novelization and (I believe) the movies.  Also, armadillos 'scales' (which are actually bony plates) don't resemble the Gremlin's skin in the least.  I doubt very much they were actually reptiles, but it's the best correlation with real animal group (specifically, ***Reptilia***) that can be drawn.

Comment: @Jeff Something can be described as reptilian without actually being a reptile- in fact, reptilian can also mean "repulsive" without talking about reptiles at all. My point with the armadillo is that not all mammals are soft and fuzzy.

Comment: The traditional witching hour is 3 am. Some recent usage extends it to midnight to 3.

Answer (score 6):

Having seen the movies as an older person, (lol) my thought on it is that it was meant for kids. Therefore it is a warning against midnight snacks- no food after midnight.  Just like children, they would be going to sleep and then eating in the morning.  So, I think that's what makes them "safe"- a good nights sleep before eating.

Comment: Hi there.  I fixed your formatting because the answer was a little difficult to comprehend.  If I changed the meaning of your answer too much, please feel free to change it back.

Comment: Gremlins was rated PG-13, had things like exploding creatures and talking about characters dying while stuck in a chimney and dressed as Santa. While the movie may have been family accessible, something tells me that this was not "meant for kids".

Comment: @phantom42: eh, depends how you judge what's appropriate for kids. Old school German fairy tales were intended for kids, and were pretty grim. The idea was to scare them away from danger. Who's to say they were wrong?

Comment: You are so right, it was meant to teach kids lessons like "Don't snack late at night." and "Don't take baths, ever."

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Would you even say those German fairy tales were *Grimm*?

Comment: @Jeff: yeah I guess they are a bit, quite a downer really. Typo in your last word there, by the way.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite seriously?

Comment: @Mithrandir: serious about what?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite `Typo in your last word there, by the way.`

Comment: @Mithrandir: naw, that’s just my very dry sense of humour.

Comment: @phantom42 - Gremlins wasn't rated PG-13. It was the reason why PG-13 was created. (Along with Temple of Doom and Poltergeist. Thanks, Spielberg!)